# Why doesn't GMSGroundOverlay Icon fill its bounds in GoogleMaps?

Tags: android, swift, google-maps

I want to add an Image to my map. This image needs to fill the bounds which i create with two coordinates, soutwest and northeast. After compiling it shows some kind of gap at the edges.
Is this a bug ?

In the image I added both coordintes southwest and northeast so you can see the gap

let overlay = GMSGroundOverlay(bounds: GMSCoordinateBounds(coordinate: northEast, coordinate: southWest), icon: UIImage(named: "appleIcon"))
[image]

Comment: Are you sure that the "appleIcon" didn't have transparent background on borders?

Comment: yes im sure. i switched to Mapbox. its a way better service than google maps